# C++ char* vs int*

Tags: c++, pointers, char, int

What is the difference between char* and int*?

For example when I ran this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
  int a[3] = {10, 20, 30};
  int *ptr2a = &a[0];
  int i;
  char line[] = "Hello";
  char *ptr2line =  &line[0];

  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    cout<<"Value of a["<<i<<"] is: "<<a[i]<<" same as "<<*(ptr2a+i);
    cout<<" Address is: "<<ptr2a+i<<" , same as "<<&a[i]<<endl;
  }

  for(i=0; i<strlen(line); i++){
    cout<<"Value of line["<<i<<"] is: "<<line[i]<<" same as "<<*(ptr2line+i);
    cout<<" Address is: "<<ptr2line+i<<" , same as "<<&line[i]<<endl;
  }

return 0;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
Value of a[0] is: 10 same as 10 Address is: 0x7fff5bf29b1c , same as 0x7fff5bf29b1c
Value of a[1] is: 20 same as 20 Address is: 0x7fff5bf29b20 , same as 0x7fff5bf29b20
Value of a[2] is: 30 same as 30 Address is: 0x7fff5bf29b24 , same as 0x7fff5bf29b24
Value of line[0] is: H same as H Address is: Hello , same as Hello
Value of line[1] is: e same as e Address is: ello , same as ello
Value of line[2] is: l same as l Address is: llo , same as llo
Value of line[3] is: l same as l Address is: lo , same as lo
Value of line[4] is: o same as o Address is: o , same as o
```

When I changed this line:

```
cout<<" Address is: "<<ptr2line+i<<" , same as "<<&line[i]<<endl;
```

to:

```
cout<<" Address is: "<<&ptr2line+i<<" , same as "<<&line[i]<<endl;
```

I got this output:

```
Value of line[0] is: H same as H Address is: 0x7fff5054bad0 , same as Hello
Value of line[1] is: e same as e Address is: 0x7fff5054bad8 , same as ello
Value of line[2] is: l same as l Address is: 0x7fff5054bae0 , same as llo
Value of line[3] is: l same as l Address is: 0x7fff5054bae8 , same as lo
Value of line[4] is: o same as o Address is: 0x7fff5054baf0 , same as o
```

In this case
Address 0x7fff5054bad0 corresponds to value of 'Hello'
        0x7fff5054bad8 corresponds to 'ello' and so on.

What would be the correct way to create a pointer that stores the address of each character of a string?

**RESOLUTION**

One method to visualize the pointers is to use  printf instead

```
printf("Value of line[%d] is: %c same as %c, Address is: %p, same as %p\n", i, line[i], *(ptr2line+i),ptr2line+i,&line[i]);
```

gives the desired output

```
Value of line[0] is: H same as H, Address is: 0x7fff54ce6ade, same as 0x7fff54ce6ade
Value of line[1] is: e same as e, Address is: 0x7fff54ce6adf, same as 0x7fff54ce6adf
Value of line[2] is: l same as l, Address is: 0x7fff54ce6ae0, same as 0x7fff54ce6ae0
Value of line[3] is: l same as l, Address is: 0x7fff54ce6ae1, same as 0x7fff54ce6ae1
Value of line[4] is: o same as o, Address is: 0x7fff54ce6ae2, same as 0x7fff54ce6ae2
```

Another solution has been outlined by @Daniel Jour below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, there's no difference (except the pointed to type, of course) between a `char *` and an `int *`. The different output you're seeing is because of [the non member overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) of `operator<<` which cause special handling for `char` and `char *`.

To "see" the pointer, you can either cast the pointer to `void const *` or call the member function directly ([live on ideone](http://ideone.com/Y6iixJ)):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char const * string = "Hello";
    std::cout << "string: " << string << std::endl
        << "casted: " << static_cast<void const*>(string) << std::endl
        << "member: ";
    std::cout.operator<<(string);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Example output:

```
string: Hello
casted: 0x2b1c038fbb7d
member: 0x2b1c038fbb7d
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointers you have created have stored the address of each character in the c-string. The issue with your output is the way <s>`std::cout`</s> `operator<<` handles c-strings. It will continue reading the next entry in memory until it reaches a null `\0` character. That's why for each line you were getting the remaining characters in the whole c-string.

EDIT: For a better understanding of what is happening, please see Daniel Jour's answer.